# Icon Character Design - name and methods

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, style-identification, character-design

Im looking for tutorials about designing characters/mascots with illustrator in a specific style viewable below. I liked this design style but the actual original tutorial page is no longer online (links to http://dinglifeblog.com/?p=219 don't work).

[image]

[Image Viewable here](http://media02.hongkiat.com/cartoon-tuts-illustrator/owl.jpg)

I have searched in google for 'icon character design' but couldn't find anything similar. Is this type of design called something specific or does anyone know a good tutorial for this type of design? It is the icon character that I am specifically intrested in.

Thanks

Comment: You can see that original tutorial by using http://archive.org to go back in time, for example **http://web.archive.org/web/20091215110855/http://dinglifeblog.com/?p=219**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your asking two questions here, one being how to design an icon and the other, how to come up with an idea for it. If you're looking to make a simplified version of something, try drawing some animals (or other things) with basic shapes or making them more cartoon-styled. Here's a link to get you started: http://doitandhow.com/2012/08/04/draw-cartoon-animals/

You can also look up some great tutorials and tips like http://vector.tutsplus.com/articles/inspiration/10-tips-for-effective-icon-design/ for getting the feel of icon design.

The last part is putting it all together in Illustrator or your chosen design program. As far as that goes, I would forgo a tutorial and experiment, since you want YOUR design, not one belonging to someone else.